# Same key already added

Tags: c#, entity-framework, parallel-processing

I have a global context defined in my class

```
private readonly MyDatabase _context;
```

There is a method in the class that I run in parallel that accesses a table on my context. This is the call on the table.

```
var tableAsList = _context.MyTable.ToList();
```

This was working for me previously. Now I am receiving the following error.

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An item with the same key has already been added.
```

I've seen others saying the issue comes from the property names being similar (difference in case), but my property names are all drastically different. here is my class.

```
public class MyTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsSub { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this error would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context isn't thread safe. You can't run multiple operations on concurrent threads. The errors that you're seeing could be from entirely different operations. You need a `lock` or some other mechanism to ensure that multiple threads aren't attempting to perform concurrent operations on the same context.

Another reason to suspect this - you mention it was working previously. That's what makes multithreading issues so much fun - they are unpredictable, and the code might appear to work. It might even work most of the time. Then suddenly it doesn't. Someone reports a bug but no one can reproduce it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sure enough that was the problem.